# Is it common to call the question mark and the exclamation mark “query” and “bang”?

Tags: frequency

According to various dictionaries, “query” is a synonym for “question mark”, and “bang” is a synonym for “exclamation mark”. I’m wondering how common these shorter forms are.

I’m a French speaker, and in French, only publishing professionals know the short names for those punctuation marks (“rog” and “clam”, short for “point d’interrogation” and “point d’exclamation”), and you won’t find them in dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve seen it in ancient documents relating to programming. So a 60 year old software developer might figure out what you are talking about. Anyone else, no.

Comment: Both are used in much more recent documents and discussion, but it's definitely IT jargon.

Comment: The first line of Unix family shell scripts is often started with two characters `#!` and the path of an executable e.g. `#!/bin/bash`, and the pair is often called a 'hashbang'. People write and discuss such scripts every day.

Comment: I have occasionally seen _query_ used for _question mark_ in contexts much older than computer programming, but I only know _bang_ from [interrobang](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interrobang).